# problem with WebView ... goes back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-webview

I have 3 activities- A, B and C. I have a list on activity A and if I click on it, it goes to activity B. On activity B, I have a button which opens activity C (web viewer) with the following code :

```
buyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyButton);

    buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           System.out.println("!!! buy !!!");

         /*Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
         startActivity(intent);*/

            Intent startActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewer.class);
            startActivity.putExtra("link","http://www.google.com");
            startActivityForResult(startActivity, 15);

        }
    });
```

Now, when I press the back button on web viewer activity C, activity B also closes. I am not sure why that is happening. Any hints ? Thanks.

webviewer code :

```
public class WebViewer extends Activity {



ImageButton backButton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.streams);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title3);

    String url = "";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        url = extras.getString("link");
    }

    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
           url = "http://" + url;

    final TextView title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text_view_success3);
    //title.setText("Saved Streams");

    backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_button3);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           System.out.println("!!! BACK !!!");
           //finishActivity(0);
           onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.viewer);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            title.setText("Loading...");
            WebViewer.this.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
            title.setText(webView.getTitle());
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);


 }



}
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are using startActivityForResult() this is causing Activity B to close.

Comment: @surisahani  : so, what do you suggest ?

Comment: Try the code by just startActivity.

Comment: @surisahani  tried, didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

change your code like below,

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

if(webView.canGoBack()){
           System.out.println("!!! BACK !!!");

           webView.goBack();
}
        }
    });
```

Comment: @llango J : the back button does the same thing as the physical back button and nothing to do with similar concept web browser back button.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one I don't think you should use getApplicationContext when creating an `Intent`. You should just use a reference to the activity you are currently in.  That way Android returns the result to that activity.

Example:

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent(MyActivity.this, WebViewer.class);
```

Comment: What didn't work about it? It sends an intent to the system saying you want to send an email.  There are many other questions telling you how to determine if no applications could handle the intent.

Comment: I meant, if I go back from the web viewer (activity C), activity B still closes and I am back at activity A. I want to be in activity B after I get back from activity C (web viewer). ...

Comment: @ahsan If the comment is correct, maybe ask the answerer to add it as the answer. I'm facing the same problem and just from the comment I haven't been able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question. but if you want to go back then use the code below. I use this code in webviewer.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mainWebView.canGoBack() == true) {
            mainWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```